# jQuery scrollTop - animation stucks at the end of moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop, smoothing

i use jquery the scrollTop function to get my scrolling smooth while switching between different anchors.
first, here is the url

[the problem](http://rose.developertinger.de/anwalte-team/gregor-rose/)

this is my jquery script

"ziel" is just the german word for "target", just to let you know why this variable is called "ziel"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var ziel = $(this).attr("href");

        $('#portraitcontent').animate({
            scrollTop: $(ziel).offset().top
        }, 3000 , function (){location.hash = ziel;});
});
return false;
});
```

so how do i get a smooth scrolling without that ugly jumping at the end of the animation?
any ideas?

i really don't know what to do. spending hours with that bitch!

thanks for your advices!

**EDIT**

Well with this new code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var ziel = $(this).attr("href");
        $('#portrait-entry').animate({
            scrollTop: $(ziel).offset().top - 230
        }, 1500 , function (){

            if(window.history.replaceState){
                window.history.replaceState(null, document.title, ziel); // <--here
            }
        });
});
return false;
});
```

smooth scrolling works without ugly jumping
**BUT** for now
my anchorlinks don't work the way they should.

please check [the problem](http://rose.developertinger.de/anwalte-team/gregor-rose/) - when you click on "fortbildungen" and then on "mitgliedschaften", it is not scrolled down to the anchor. 
i think i have to do reset or s.th. like that, because i think when you are on a #anchor page, the links dont work how they should.

i'm not into js/jquery. so maybe someone could give me a advice. i don't know how to google this kind of problem.

thank you for your help and for the edited code, which made my scrolling smooth.

Comment: In your callback function of your animation, you tell the window to perform that jump by setting the `location.hash = ziel`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to delete this scrollTop code and switch to the 
jQuery.scrollTo plugin in combination with jQuery.localScroll.

Just to let you know

Answer (score 0):

Just because you changed the url in the animate callback cause ugly jumping.

A solution for html5 capable browser is that using "window.history.replaceState" to change url instead of changing url directlly.

The code would like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var ziel = $(this).attr("href");

        $('#portraitcontent').animate({
            scrollTop: $(ziel).offset().top
        }, 2500 , function (){

            if(window.history.replaceState){
                window.history.replaceState(null, document.title, ziel); // <--here
            }
        });
});
return false;
});
```